# Match string "ces" in the Last Three Letters

Tags: regex, mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to know how to find something using only the last three letters of its name in mongodb, with the structure db.collection.find(), thank's!

```js
  {  
    "address": {
      "building": "1007",
      "coord": [ -73.856077, 40.848447 ],
      "street": "Morris Park Ave",
      "zipcode": "10462"
    },
    "borough": "Bronx",
    "cuisine": "Bakery",
    "grades": [
      { "date": { "$date": 1393804800000 }, "grade": "A", "score": 2 },
      { "date": { "$date": 1378857600000 }, "grade": "A", "score": 6 },
      { "date": { "$date": 1358985600000 }, "grade": "A", "score": 10 },
      { "date": { "$date": 1322006400000 }, "grade": "A", "score": 9 },
      { "date": { "$date": 1299715200000 }, "grade": "B", "score": 14 }
    ],  
    "name": "Morris Park Bake Shop",
    "restaurant_id": "30075445"
  }
```

My current try:

```js
db.mycollection.find({},{name:"ces"})
```

Comment: In future it would be helpful to include some data in your question that would actually match the query condition(s) you want. The `"name"` field here does not end in `"ces"` or even contain those letters in any part of the string.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on whether you mean *"last three letters of the word"* or *"last three letters of the 'field'"* then you generally want a [`$regex`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/)

On this data:

```js
{ "_id" : ObjectId("570462448c0fd5187b53985a"), "name" : "Bounces" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5704624d8c0fd5187b53985b"), "name" : "Something" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5704625b8c0fd5187b53985c"), "name" : "Bounces Something" }
```

Then the query for the "word", where `\b` means "word boundary", and escaped by `\` in the "string" expression:

```js
db.collection.find({ "name": { "$regex": "ces\\b" } })
```

Which matches:

```js
{ "_id" : ObjectId("570462448c0fd5187b53985a"), "name" : "Bounces" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5704625b8c0fd5187b53985c"), "name" : "Bounces Something" }
```

Or the query for the "field", where `$` means *"from the end*":

```js
db.collection.find({ "name": { "$regex": "ces$" } })
```

Which matches:

```js
{ "_id" : ObjectId("570462448c0fd5187b53985a"), "name" : "Bounces" }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try any of these:

- `db.hotels.find({name: /ces$/})`
- `db.hotels.find({name: {$regex: "ces$"}})`
- `db.hotels.find({name: {$regex: /ces$/}})`